# CoffeeScript: Error When Instantiating Object In Constructor

Tags: javascript, oop, coffeescript

I'm getting a weird error when trying to instantiate an object inside of another object's constructor method.

**EDIT 3**

For instance (with pictures):

Here's the javascript

[image]

Here's the compiled coffeescript

[image]

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: I guess he meant [this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20MyClass%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40object%20%3D%20new%20obj()%0A%20%20%20%20%40foo%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%20%20%40bar%20%3D%20%5B%5D), though it still doesn't produce the output he posted. Connor, please show us a complete example that demonstrates this behaviour.

Comment: The indentation in your question is not the indentation in your CoffeeScript. Your `@foo` and `@bar` assignments are at the same level as `constructor`, they're not inside it; see [this example](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20MyClass%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%40object%20%3D%20new%20obj()%0A%20%20%40foo%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%40bar%20%3D%20%5B%5D) if you don't believe me.

Comment: Are you sure your example CoffeeScript isn't missing an `extends`?

Comment: Are you certain than you're not mixing spaces and tabs? I can  reproduce your input and output by indenting the `@foo` and `@bar` with tabs (and a four space tab stop) but the rest with spaces.

Comment: @muistooshort, you are correct

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably have wrong indentation. Only the `@object = new obj()` is considered to belong to the `constructor` code, and following lines will become properties of the constructor function itself.

If you can't see that, you might have non-blank or non-tab characters in your code. Also make sure you're only using either tabs *or* blanks, not (as [mu is too short](https://stackoverflow.com/users/479863/mu-is-too-short) points out), a mix of them.

> Is it bad programming practice to have an object as member data of another object in javascript?

Absolutely not, especially since functions are objects as well. And nearly all JSON or XML data comes nested. What makes you think this could be a bad practise?

Comment: Ah, [like this](http://coffeescript.org/#try:class%20MyClass%0A%20%20constructor%3A%20-%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%40object%20%3D%20new%20obj()%0A%20%20%40foo%20%3D%20%5B%5D%0A%20%20%40bar%20%3D%20%5B%5D). Nice catch.